# OpenCV: How to get features with cv2.CascadeClassifier?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, opencv3.0, object-detection

I know that `haarcascade.xml` describes some features of some object we want to detect. E.g. face has a nose, eyes and it is ellipse or auto-plates has a line of digits and letters with specific size and proportion.

If we use:

```
cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade.xml')
objects = cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1, 3)
```

we will get a list of box parameters `(x,y,w,h)`

Is there any way to get all features parameters?

e.g.
if haarcascade describes face I want to get nose coordinates (without using additional haarcascade) or if haarcascade describes auto-plates I want to get coordinates of each symbol.

Comment: haar cascades dont work that way. The features used for detection probably don't correspond with 'your' wanted features.

Comment: haar cascades is haar feature based object detection mechanism. It will not give you co-ordinates. It matches based on haar features.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this paper [Rapid Object Detection using a Boosted Cascade of Simple Features](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~efros/courses/LBMV07/Papers/viola-cvpr-01.pdf). It explains the implementation of the cascade. As you can see they use [Haar Features](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar-like_features), so you won't be able to extract that information. But there is a special cascade for [detecting eyes](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d7/d8b/tutorial_py_face_detection.html). Maybe this helps you. You can find all other pretrained cascades [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/data/haarcascades). If you want to extract the nose position you may need to train your own cascade or search for an .xml file for that.